# Concept question. JButton existence after creating object of class JButton. Mock test question

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

When I create object of class JButton. Does it create the button simultaneously? Is it just invisible?
So if I have a question that gives me a code:

`JButton mybutton = new JButton("ABC")`

I have 3 variants of answer.

The code creates:

a) The object of a class JButton

b) The button, which is not visible until it is added to the content pane of a window

c) The button with the text "ABC" on it

There can be more than one right answer.

I did my research but I don't really understand if it is possible that something except for A is true

Comment: All 3 are true.

Answer (score 0):

When you create object of button at that time, button is created but it is not shown because every these type of elements requires layout for visibility

Comment: Actually it requires to be in a ContentPane, which requires to have a Layout.

Comment: ContentPane is a layout

Comment: but until this button is not attached to this layout, it remains invisible

Comment: *"ContentPane is a layout"* The content pane is a `JComponent` (a `JPanel`) which **has a** layout (by default, a `BorderLayout`). 'Is a' & 'has a' are separate things.